PDFBOX read Skia created PDF file
I read PDF file (Skia/PDF m118 Google Docs Renderer) with PDFBOX but it reads nothing. The document has only one page and does not contain images. I try to read content with PDFTextStripper.
Any idea how read Skia/PDF m118 Google Docs with PDFBOX?
I can open it with Acrobat Reader.
Code snippet
    Document dataDocument = new Document();
    try {
        PDFTextStripper pdfTextStripper = new PDFTextStripper();

        pdfTextStripper.setParagraphStart("/t");
        pdfTextStripper.setSortByPosition(true);

        for (int i = 0; i < document.getNumberOfPages(); i++) {
            pdfTextStripper.setStartPage(i);
            pdfTextStripper.setEndPage(i);
            for (String line : pdfTextStripper.getText(document).split(pdfTextStripper.getParagraphStart())) {
                if (!line.isBlank() && line.length() > 3) {
                    dataDocument.getText().add(line);
                }
            }
            dataDocument.getText().add(":page=" + i);
        }

...
PdfBox version
 implementation 'org.apache.pdfbox:pdfbox:2.0.30'

Pdf file
This is a link for the document, https://jmp.sh/s/vTpGFHq6nLjzWXzBfxIA
Zlaja

"Unfortunately i can not share document" - that's unfortunate as this apparently is a problem specific to the type of your document. But in your question you ask how read Skia/PDF. So you must have tested with lots of different Skia generated PDFs to determine that your issue indeed occurs for such documents in general. So there surely is one of them you can share...

I've just added document link!

Ok. I'll look at it later this week. Maybe @tilman has some time before that.

I've upgraded to 2.0.31 but without any change. I can Save as Text from Adobe Reader and get a text file with pdf content. I've noticed that every word is new line in that file.

Here is a new link, https://drive.google.com/file/d/1dihCDkH4c0vv_IP0xPYFkbk_WJQK4wvl/view?usp=share_link

I get "Ovo je neki primer tekst t" when using ExtractText. I didn't test your code, I wonder if the split() has some bad effect depending on the parameter content.

I've tried pdfTextStripper.getText(document), without split but get no text.

Both setStartPage() and setEndPage() require the parameter to be 1-based (see javadoc). Thus change your code to:
pdfTextStripper.setStartPage(i + 1);
pdfTextStripper.setEndPage(i + 1);


Ah, good, not Skia-related after all.... (Maybe the code should emit a warning if called with non-positive startPage or endPage.)

Yes, a good question. If pages start from index 1 then it should be even an error.
